# Correct way of using prepared statement in php along with procedure

Tags: php, mysql

**Procedure**

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE prSample1()
      BEGIN    
        SELECT Name
          FROM StudentsList;
      END;
```

**PHP Code**

```
     $objMain = new Main();  
      $objMain->getStudentsName();

      class Main
      {
        function __construct()
        {
          $Conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'sampleDB');              
        }

        function getStudentsName() 
        {
           $strSQL = "CALL prSample1()";
           $stmt   = $Conn->prepare($strSQL); 

           $stmt->execute();
           $stmt->bind_result($Name);   

           while($stmt->fetch())
            $arrNames = array('Name'=>$Name); 
        }
```

I don't get any error or any warning.

I would like to Know the effect of the Following statements on the php code after getting the values in array that is before the last brace ends.

```
    1.$stmt->close()
    2.$stmt->reset()
```

Also let me know where to use the following statements and how to use them

```
    1.$stmt->free_result()
    2.$stmt->store_result() 
    3.$stmt->bind_result()
```

Please correct me if I have did any mistakes in coding standards and proper way to use prepared statements

Comment: The correct way to use a prepared statement is to simply not use one when you don't have any input parameters! That aside, why are you using a stored procedure for such a simple `SELECT` statement?

Comment: No I posted a sample code I use prepared statements only when i need to make some operations store values in temp tables and return those back